figures without captions
i'm trying to create a report that includes a table and figure side by side. For the report i do not need any captions and am struggling to find a solution. I am using Tex within R Markdown. I have successfully deleted the caption under the table with \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} but for some reason the same code does not work for the caption under the figure (see below)
\newfloatcommand{btabbox}{table}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{floatrow}
    \btabbox{%
```{r, fig.align = "right", echo = F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE)
knitr::kable(art, format = "latex")

}{\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}}
\caption{}
\ffigbox{%

knitr::include_graphics("output.pdf")

}{\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}}
{\caption{}}

  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}



you don't need a float or caption so there is nothing special you need to do: \begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\includegraphics{...}  will put a table and image side by side,

@DavidCarlisle - I inserted the R chunks that create the table and insert the graphic where the ... are in the above code and i get a "Paragraph ended before @array was complete.  \par 1.77" error.  I'm super green to LaTex script so I dont understand what this means.  Do I need to keep   \begin{figure} \end{figure} ?

if you can show the generated latex document we could probably help, my R is too rusty, but someone else may answer directly on the R syntax,

@DavidCarlisle - i looked at the .tex doc and \begin{tabular} / \end{tabular} were redundant.  I assume that was because Rmarkdown is wrapping the R chunks with those "behind the scenes". I removed those lines from my .rmd and the error went away and a .pdf was created.  However, while the table is on the left and figure on the right, they are not side-by-side
